# Error: Could not find or load main class excel2JSON.excel

Tags: java, json, excel

```
package excel2JSON;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = ExcelToJSON(new File ("C:\\workbook.xlsx"));
        System.out.println("JSON =  " + str);
    }

    private static String ExcelToJSON(File file_open) 
    {

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file_open);
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(input);

                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                json = new JSONObject();

                JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();
                for (Iterator<Row> rows_it = sheet.rowIterator(); rows_it.hasNext();) {
                    Row row = rows_it.next();
                    JSONObject jason_row = new JSONObject();


                    JSONArray cells = new JSONArray();
    for (Iterator<Cell> cells_it = row.cellIterator(); cells_it.hasNext();) {
                        Cell cell = cells_it.next();

                        //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                        {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                             double numeric=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                cells.put(String.valueOf(numeric));
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                cells.put(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    jason_row.put("cell", cells);
                    rows.put(jason_row);
                }

                // Create the JSON.
                json.put("rows", rows);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Get the JSON text.
            return json.toString();
        }
}
```

getting this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class excel2JSON.excel

I don't know why i am getting this error. I am new to Java and i need help to fix this issue. I am trying to convert Excel file to JSON document. This is the code i wrote for that but i am getting issue when i run the program in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this error in eclipse is when you have moved the class around, Eclipse will be trying to use an outdated run configuration which will not work.

Click the down arrow next to the green play button in Eclipse, select Run Configurations.

Delete the references to this class, then close that window, select the excel class. Click the down arrow next to the play button again and select run as Java Application.